# Report > Customers by order totals only shows 5 results

Tags: customer, reports

I am currently trying to run the Customers by Order Totals report in Magento Community, this is stored in Reports > Customers > Customers by Order Totals, currently when I try and run in month, year view, I am only getting 5 customers per month or per year, I want to show more 5 results. Can you help me about this

Any ideas?

Comment: Please update your question: What version of Magento are you using? Clean Magento or any extensions that might disrupt this? Did you do any custom changes? Right now we do not have enough information to be able to help you out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of results is limited directly on the report block class code. You can create a module or make an override to change this value. I would create a module that would add a field to the configuration panel (using system.xml) to be free to change this value at any time.

The limit is defined in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid`.

File: app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Report\Grid.php

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    ... 
    protected $_subReportSize = 5;
    ...
}
```

**NOTE: Do not change the code directly into the core!**